# Printing a tuple instead of text

Tags: python-2.7

```
x= input('What is your name? ')

print('Heloo',x)
```

The above code is giving an output  `('Heloo', 5)` for the input as `5`.
The above code is giving an output  `('Heloo', 'shubham')` for the input as `'shubham'`.
The above code is giving an error for the input as `shubham` without quotes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SHUBHAM/Desktop/Python1.py", line 1, in <module>
    x= input('What is your name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'shubham' is not defined
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the error with my code?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

`shubham` is not defined. It works for `x` because you are asking the user to define `x`, which is why when you call on it to print it works. It works in quotes because you are telling Python that it is a string but when you leave it without quotes it assumes it is a variable, but since you have not assigned anything to it, it gives you this error.

Comment: But why this print is giving me a tuple output?

Comment: Because you wrapped your `print` statement with parenthesis. Take them off and you will get this

Comment: And for the command print ('Heloo world')  there it gives a string output. why?

Comment: Because you have your print statement wrapped in quotes. If that's not your question then it is because "Hello world" is wrapped in quotes. Honestly I am sure this question has been asked many times before.